# Getting NullPointerException: on GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean) on a null object reference

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-maps, nullpointerexception

I get this error

NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(boolean) on a null object reference

and the app crashes due to this error.i want to mentioned that i searched on the internet and here for an answer but not found anything

Here is my code:

```
public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private GoogleMap googleMap;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> arrayPoints = null;
    PolylineOptions polylineOptions;
    private boolean checkClick = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        arrayPoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
        // Obtain the SupportMapFragment and get notified when the map is ready to be used.
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);

        // display zoom map

        googleMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        googleMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        googleMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

    }

    public GoogleMap getmMap() {
        return mMap;

    }


    /**
     * Manipulates the map once available.
     * This callback is triggered when the map is ready to be used.
     * This is where we can add markers or lines, add listeners or move the camera. In this case,
     * we just add a marker near Sydney, Australia.
     * If Google Play services is not installed on the device, the user will be prompted to install
     * it inside the SupportMapFragment. This method will only be triggered once the user has
     * installed Google Play services and returned to the app.
     */


    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {

        mMap = googleMap;
        googleMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng latLng) {

                if (checkClick == false) {

                    LatLng currentLocation = null;
                    Marker marker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(currentLocation)
                            .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromResource(R.drawable.point)));

                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {

        googleMap.clear();
        arrayPoints.clear();
        checkClick = false;

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        System.out.println("Marker lat long=" + marker.getPosition());
        System.out.println("First postion check" + arrayPoints.get(0));
        System.out
                .println("**********All arrayPoints***********" + arrayPoints);
        if (arrayPoints.get(0).equals(marker.getPosition())) {
            System.out.println("********First Point choose************");
            countPolygonPoints();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void countPolygonPoints() {

        if (arrayPoints.size() >= 3) {
            checkClick = true;
            PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
            polygonOptions.addAll(arrayPoints);
            polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
            polygonOptions.strokeWidth(7);
            polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
            Polygon polygon = googleMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple issues in your code.

First of all, you are using two `GoogleMap` variables and not correctly initializing either. You only need one.

```
private GoogleMap mMap;
```

Secondly, in order to use `setMyLocationEnabled` you need to request location permissions from the user at runtime:

```
if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
        ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
    mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
    mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
}
```

Then you are setting `currentLocation` to `null` and passing this null variable to your new marker. Instead, use the actual `latLng`:

```
mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
```

Finally, you are not actually adding any items to your `arrayPoints` ArrayList. I'd assume you want to do something like this:

```
arrayPoints.add(marker.getPosition());
```

Full working code below.

```
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat;
import androidx.fragment.app.FragmentActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.OnMapReadyCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.SupportMapFragment;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.LatLng;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.Marker;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.MarkerOptions;
import com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolygonOptions;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MapsActivity extends FragmentActivity
        implements OnMapReadyCallback,
        GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMapLongClickListener,
        GoogleMap.OnMarkerClickListener {

    private GoogleMap mMap;
    private ArrayList<LatLng> arrayPoints = null;
    private boolean checkClick = false;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_maps);

        arrayPoints = new ArrayList<>();
        SupportMapFragment mapFragment = (SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.map);
        mapFragment.getMapAsync(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapReady(final GoogleMap googleMap) {
        mMap = googleMap;

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) ==
                PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            mMap.setMyLocationEnabled(true);
            mMap.getUiSettings().setMyLocationButtonEnabled(true);
        }

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMapLongClickListener(this);
        mMap.setOnMarkerClickListener(this);

        mMap.setOnMapClickListener(new GoogleMap.OnMapClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onMapClick(final LatLng latLng) {
                if (!checkClick) {
                    mMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(latLng));
                }
            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapLongClick(LatLng latLng) {
        mMap.clear();
        arrayPoints.clear();
        checkClick = false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onMarkerClick(Marker marker) {
        arrayPoints.add(marker.getPosition());
        System.out.println("Marker lat long=" + marker.getPosition());
        System.out.println("First position check" + arrayPoints.get(0));
        System.out
                .println("**********All arrayPoints***********" + arrayPoints);
        if (arrayPoints.get(0).equals(marker.getPosition())) {
            System.out.println("********First Point choose************");
            countPolygonPoints();
        }
        return false;
    }

    private void countPolygonPoints() {
        if (arrayPoints.size() >= 3) {
            checkClick = true;
            PolygonOptions polygonOptions = new PolygonOptions();
            polygonOptions.addAll(arrayPoints);
            polygonOptions.strokeColor(Color.BLUE);
            polygonOptions.strokeWidth(7);
            polygonOptions.fillColor(Color.CYAN);
            mMap.addPolygon(polygonOptions);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onMapClick(LatLng latLng) {

    }
}
```

Hope this helps!